# Visual Debugger for Geometric Objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, vspackage, vs-extensibility, geometry-class-library

When working on my library representing geometric objects, Debugging currently looks like this:

[image]

Here I am viewing the local variables in the `Autos`, `Locals`, `Watch` and `Immediate` windows.

As I have trouble imagining the shape of the object in my mind, I would prefer a graphical component to represent these objects. So I have started creating a Debugger Visualizer to draw the objects. I have it in a public repo on bitbucket [here](https://bitbucket.org/Clearspan/geometry-visual-debugger).

Right now I cannot get it to work outside of the Console Application I have in the solution with it. What am I doing wrong?

here is what it looks like when it works:

[image]

Also, How can I do this in a way that will allow me to view multiple objects at a time. I realized that I really want to see multiple objects and their interactions, instead of just the single objects. (e.g Look for intersections and such).

P.S.

Has anyone seen a debugger extension anywhere like this? or have any suggestions of how I can fix my current one?

I have attempted this in the form of a Visual Studio Extension with no success as well. [See this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239792/call-function-of-visual-studio-package).

Comment: do you know the `Immediate Window`?

Comment: the `Immediate Window` can help you, Create a function for this and call it on Immediate Window. I always use the Immediate Window, this is very very better than others

Comment: Not sure I understand what your envisioning in this function you suggest.. In this function I would have to create and open a form to draw on, yes?

Comment: even you can do this. This is a very very powerful tool

Comment: I think what you are looking for debugger visualizer!

Comment: I tried your repro but got stuck on line 46 of PointVisualizer: `Type 'GeometryClassLibrary.Point' in Assembly 'GeometryClassLibrary, Version=1.0.5381.24470, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.`

Answer (score 3):

One possible option for you would be downloading the compiled DLL from

[Graphics Debugger Visualizer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24211/Graphics-Debugger-Visualizer)

and decompressing them into your Debugger\Visualizers folder. Somewhere like

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\

Then restart your visual Studio. As soon soon you start debugging you will see Graphic debugger sign 
next to the run-time value of the Graphics variable as described in the codeproject solution I mentioned earlier.

**Update 1:**
I also highly recommend you to have a look at the following blog where S.Ullah the author of Custom Visual Studio Visualizer illustrates how to create a visualizer for in memory graphics:

[Custom Visual Studio Visualizer](http://geekswithblogs.net/technetbytes/archive/2008/06/11/122792.aspx)

There used to be commercially available product called [Mole](http://www.molosoft.com/download/mole-2013-version-3-0/) however it is no longer available for new buyers(I don't know why)

Comment: Agreed it's bad to down vote without a clarification, so up voted to counter :)